# 2x2 system with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So I have a simple 2x2 system:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     x' = \frac{-1}{10}x + \frac{1}{20}y  \\
     y' = \frac{3}{80}x + \frac{-1}{20}y
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I have solved the general solution to be:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     X(t) = c_1\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{\frac{-1}{8}t} + 
            c_2\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}e^{\frac{-1}{40}t}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The 1st initial condition is $x(0) = 0$ (1).
The 2nd initial condition is $x_{max} = 1000$ which happens at $x'(t) = 0$ (2)
**The question is to find $y(0)$ which corresponded to $x_{max} = 1000$ or $x'(t) = 0$.**

(1) derives $c_1 = c_2$.

**I'm not sure how to use (2)?**

I took the derivative of $x'(t)$:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     x'(t) & = 0 \\
     \frac{c_1}{4}e^{\frac{-1}{8}t} + \frac{-c_2}{20}e^{\frac{-1}{40}t} & = 0 \\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which is not helpful even when substituting $c_1 = c_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the equation you have derived and plugging $c = c_1=c_2$, we have

$$c\left(\frac{\exp(-t/8)}{4} - \frac{\exp(-t/40)}{20}\right) = 0$$

Since $c \neq 0$, we have

$$5\exp(-t/8) = \exp(-t/40)$$

$$\implies 5 = \exp(t/10)$$

$$\implies t = 10 \ln 5$$

Now you plug that into $x(t)$ and solve for $x_{max} = 1000$ to get $c$ value

Comment: wow i am dumb, missed the obvious - sign